# HTML page compiling LaTeX code to nice mathematics display - 2nd attempt

Tags: javascript, html, tex

I have [this](http://coderodde.github.io/latexconsole/) page that allows a user to quickly compile \$\LaTeX\$ code into a mathematical display. Whenever the user compiles the code, that page also generates an URL from which it is possible to view the output simply by visiting the URL:

[image: Demonstration]

**index.html** (Note that this Stack Snippet generates non-working URLs because it is on a different domain):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
            MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" async
                src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function get_url_parameter(param)
            {
                var page_url = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var url_vars = page_url.split('&');

                for (var i = 0; i < url_vars.length; ++i) 
                {
                    var param_name = url_vars[i].split('=');

                    if (param_name[0] == param) 
                    {
                        return param_name[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

        <title>LaTeX console</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Type in the LaTeX code and press <b>Compile!</b></h1>

        <div align="center" style="margin: 30px;">
            <p id="latex_output">
                {06f672e0-065e-445d-8e16-0790142de8ab}
            </p>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
            <h3>Input area</h3>
            <textarea id="latex_input" rows="5" cols="80">{bcd26d9d-9bcd-40d8-9357-ef17752144a1}</textarea>
        </div>

        <div align="center" style="margin: 30px;">
            <button type="button" id="compile_button">Compile!</button>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
            <h3>URL to share</h3>
            <textarea id="encoded_url_textarea" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea>
        </div>

        <script>
            compile_button       = document.getElementById("compile_button");
            latex_output         = document.getElementById("latex_output");
            latex_input          = document.getElementById("latex_input");
            encoded_url_textarea = document.getElementById("encoded_url_textarea");

            compile_button.onclick = function() { 
                latex_output.innerHTML = latex_input.value;
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
                encoded_url_textarea.value = location.protocol +
                                             '//' +
                                             location.host +
                                             location.pathname +
                                             "?code=" +
                                             encodeURIComponent(latex_input.value);
            };

            var code = get_url_parameter("code");

            if (code) 
            {
                latex_input.value = decodeURIComponent(code);
                latex_output.innerHTML = latex_input.value;
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As always, any critique is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just go through this as I find issues:

1. Don't declare your main dependency as `async`. In case the server goes down that makes **your page** look stupid. What you should do instead is check that the script was actually loaded before trying to use it.
2. JS standard naming convention for functions is `camelCase`. see the js-standard api as well as every major js framework. This is not python: `get_url_parameter` \$\rightarrow\$ `getUrlParameter`.
   Same applies for variable names throughout your code.
3. Use `'use strict'` to force compliance to new JS standards. And use it in the largest scope you control alone:

   ```
   function getUrlParameter(param) {
       'use strict'
       let pageUrl =  // ...
   ```
4. I like how you encapsulated the parameter getting into it's own method. I also like how you use standard functions to URI-encode correctly instead of rolling your own encoding
5. Last time I checked (which is a while ago) it was common to wrap top-level code into a self-executing function like this:

   ```
   (function() {
       // ... 
   })();
   ```

   the main reason why is outlined [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1803692)
6. use `let` over `var` to communicate mutability intents to other developers (and the script engine). Also don't rely on implicit variable declaration. that's cheap :)
7. I never understood the point of aligning an assignment operation's right hand side :/
8. You can make things a tad easier when creating the `encodedUrlTextarea.value` by using template interpolation:

   ```
   encodedUrlTextarea.value = `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}?code=${encodeURIComponent(latexInput.value)}`;
   ```

   This can be made a bit cleaner with some extraction:

   ```
   let baseUrl = `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}`;
   let code = encodeURIComponent(latexInput.value);
   encodedUrlTextarea.value = `${baseUrl}?code=${code}`;
   ```

   As we can see, the creation of `baseUrl` can be pulled out of the function. It won't change during the script lifetime. Take advantage of that. It's definitely debatable whether the call to `encodeURIComponent` now really needs to be outside the template string